# How to read all new rows from database?

Tags: c#, oledbdatareader

I am trying to read all new rows that are added to the database on a timer.

First I read the entire database and save it to a local data table, but I want to read all new rows that are added to the database. Here is how I'm trying to read new rows:

```
string accessDB1 = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} ORDER BY ID DESC", tableName);
setupaccessDB(accessDB1);

int dTRows = localDataTable.Rows.Count + 1;
localDataTable.Rows.Add();

using (readNext = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (readNext.Read())
    {
        for (int xyz = 0; xyz < localDataTable.Columns.Count; xyz++)
        {
            // Code
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

If only 1 row is added within the timer then this works fine, but when multiple rows are added this only reads the latest row.

So is there any way I can read all added rows.

I am using `OledbDataReader`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A DataAdapter will do that for you

Comment: New rows? How are you keeping track of new rows? Is there an identity or something that you then store when you have "read" it

Comment: I run a query to count the no. of rows in the database and compare that to the previous no. of rows. If its greater I execute the above code

Comment: The count is not enough information for this.  If you have 9 rows add 1 and delete 1 you still have 9 rows, but one *is* new.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem lies here:

```
while (readNext.Read())
{
    doSomething();
    break;
}
```

This is what your loop basically boils down to. That `break` is going to exit the loop after processing the first item, regardless of how many items there are.

The first item, in this case, will probably be the last one added (as you state it is) since you're sorting by descending `ID`.

In terms of reading only newly added rows, there are a variety of ways to do it, some which will depend on the DBMS that you're using.

Perhaps the simplest and most portable would be to add an extra column `processed` which is set to false when a row is first added.

That way, you can simply have a query that looks for those records and, for each, process them and set the column to true.

In fact, you could use triggers to do this (force the flag to false on insertion) which opens up the possibility for doing it with updates as well.

Tracking deletions is a little more difficult but still achievable. You could have a trigger which actually writes the record to a separate table before deleting it so that your processing code has access to those details as well.

Comment: When I try your code everything from the database is read instead of only new rows. (I got rid of the 'break').
Is there a link where I can learn how to use Select statements, so far I've learnt it based on how other people have used Select statements.

Comment: @ghostwar, yes, that will be the effect since your query asks for all records. Have added further information on possible ways to alleviate this other issue.

Answer (score 1):

For most tables the primary key is based an incremental value. This can be a very simple integer that is incremented by one, but it could also be a datetime based guid.

Anyway if you know the id of the last record. You can simple ask for all records that have a 'higher' id. In that way you do get the new records, but what about updated records? If you also want those you might want to use a column that contains a datetime value.

A little bit more trickier are records that are deleted from the database. You can't retrieve those with a basic query. You could solve that by setting a TTL for each record you retrieve from the database much like a cache. When the record is 'expired', you try to retrieve it again.

Some databases like Microsoft SQL Server also provide more advanced options into this regard. You can use query notifications via the broker services or enable change tracking on your database. The last one can even indicate what was the last action per record (insert, update or delete).

Answer (score 0):

The following works

```
using (readNext = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (readNext.Read())
    {
        abc = readNext.FieldCount;
        for (int s = 1; s < abc; s++)
        {
            var nextValue = readNext.GetValue(s);
        }
    }

}
```

The `For Loop` reads the current row and then the `While Loop` moves onto the next row